# There is already a virtual axis named Horizontal registered. UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)

Tags: unity3d

Использую стандартный CrossPlatformInput в unity. Когда перехожу на сцену в первый раз, то все нормально. А когда во второй выдает такие ошибки:

```
There is already a virtual axis named Horizontal registered.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.VirtualInput:RegisterVirtualAxis(VirtualAxis) (at Assets/Standard Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/VirtualInput.cs:38)
UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.CrossPlatformInputManager:RegisterVirtualAxis(VirtualAxis) (at Assets/Standard Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/CrossPlatformInputManager.cs:59)
UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.Joystick:CreateVirtualAxes() (at Assets/Standard Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/Joystick.cs:64)
UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.Joystick:OnEnable() (at Assets/Standard Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/Joystick.cs:30)


There is already a virtual axis named Vertical registered.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.VirtualInput:RegisterVirtualAxis(VirtualAxis) (at Assets/Standard Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/VirtualInput.cs:38)
UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.CrossPlatformInputManager:RegisterVirtualAxis(VirtualAxis) (at Assets/Standard Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/CrossPlatformInputManager.cs:59)
UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.Joystick:CreateVirtualAxes() (at Assets/Standard Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/Joystick.cs:69)
UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput.Joystick:OnEnable() (at Assets/Standard Assets/CrossPlatformInput/Scripts/Joystick.cs:30)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в файле Joystick.cs в метод создания Осей добавить проверку, вот мой пример который работает

```
void CreateVirtualAxes()
    {
        // set axes to use
        m_UseX = (axesToUse == AxisOption.Both || axesToUse == AxisOption.OnlyHorizontal);
        m_UseY = (axesToUse == AxisOption.Both || axesToUse == AxisOption.OnlyVertical);

        // create new axes based on axes to use
        if (m_UseX)
        {
            if (CrossPlatformInputManager.AxisExists (horizontalAxisName)) {
                CrossPlatformInputManager.UnRegisterVirtualAxis (horizontalAxisName);
            } 
                m_HorizontalVirtualAxis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis (horizontalAxisName);
                CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis (m_HorizontalVirtualAxis);

        }
        if (m_UseY)
        {
            if (CrossPlatformInputManager.AxisExists (verticalAxisName)) {
                CrossPlatformInputManager.UnRegisterVirtualAxis (verticalAxisName);
            } 

                m_VerticalVirtualAxis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis (verticalAxisName);
                CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis (m_VerticalVirtualAxis);

        }
    }
```

Добавил вот эти две проверки

> if (CrossPlatformInputManager.AxisExists (horizontalAxisName)) {
>                   CrossPlatformInputManager.UnRegisterVirtualAxis (horizontalAxisName);
>               }
>
> if (CrossPlatformInputManager.AxisExists (verticalAxisName)) {
>                   CrossPlatformInputManager.UnRegisterVirtualAxis (verticalAxisName);
>               }

Answer (score 0):

Ну CrossPlatformInput вроде статически регистрирует оси, ну и при первом заходе регает, а при повторном ругается, что зарегано уже. Проверяйте перед регистрацией, не зарегано ли уже